# Ruby: starting thin as deamon returns Bad File Descriptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

Starting the Ruby thin client works fine in command line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec thin --ssl-disable-verify -C services/private_pub/private_pub_thin.yml start
```

But starting it as deamon returns a Bad File Descriptor:

```
user@app:~/app$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec thin -d --ssl-disable-verify -C services/private_pub/private_pub_thin.yml start
user@app:~/app$ /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:149:in ``': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:149:in `block in git'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:72:in `call'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:72:in `with_clean_git_env'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:149:in `git'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:83:in `version'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/env.rb:78:in `git_version'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/env.rb:22:in `report'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:74:in `request_issue_report_for'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:40:in `log_error'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Any idea? This happened without any code change. There is also nothing already running.

Comment: i have no idea, but just throwing this out: in production you have `-d`. Is that the prob?

Comment: Yep, that is the problem. But not the solution! -d = daemon, as in exactly the thing I want to work but doesn't.